# Are curves in a level set continuous?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Wikipedia defines a level set as

> a *level set* of a real-valued function of $n$ real variables $f$ is a set of the form $$L_c(f) = \left\{ (x_1, \cdots, x_n) \, \mid \, f(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = c \right\}$$

I often seen level sets drawn as curves in $\Bbb{R}^2$ like this

[image]

**My Question:**

Why do we assume a level set is continuous? Why couldn't it be just a collection of random points all with the same value instead of curves?

Comment: Usually level sets are defined for continuous function.

Comment: you are correct that if $f$ is "bad" you won't get nice level sets. You need some kind of smoothness condition to get well behaved regions.

Comment: Does the wording, "What justifies the usual picture of level sets (of a real-valued function of two real variables) as smooth curves?", capture the intent of the question?

Comment: The notion of "continuous curve" isn't so clear if you're talking about a set of points in $\mathbb R^2$; more or less, the [implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) tells us about how nice level sets have to be.

Comment: @Meelo can you elaborate on the relationship between the implicit function theorem and level sets? That sounds very interesting

Answer (score 8):

If $f$ is continuous, then the level set $\{f=c\}$ has to be closed. That's about all you can say: Given an arbitrary closed subset $E$ of $\mathbb {R}^n,$ there is $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb {R}^n)$ such that $\{f=0\} =E.$ To get nice smooth things as level sets, there is usually an added assumption hanging around, such as $\nabla f\ne 0$ on $E.$

Comment: What's more, if $E$ has no accumulation points, there are also analytic such $f$.

Comment: Why does the level set have to be closed?

Comment: The inverse image of a closed set is closed for a continuous function. Less fancy: If  $x_n$ is a sequence in $\{f=c\}$ and $x_n \to x $ then $f(x)=\lim f(x_n) =c$ by continuity. Therefore $x\in \{f=c\}.$

Answer (score 4):

If you have a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and want to look at $A=f^{-1}(\{c\})$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, you can say $A$ is an embedded $n-1$ manifold in $\mathbb{R^n}$, provided that the gradient is not zero in any point of $A$. This follows from the inverse function theorem.

In your image, you are looking at the level set of a function $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, if all points are "well-behaved" on the pre-image of a given value, you will have a curve as a level set (a closed loop or a curve that goes to infinity, by a characterization of 1-manifolds).

Notice that this is not always the case! Take $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=xy$ for instance. Then $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is the union of the two axis, which is not a 1-manifold.

Comment: Why would a nonzero derivative imply the point is a 1-manifold (which is indeed absurd as you say)?

Comment: Due to the first thing I wrote: if all of the points of the level set have non-zero derivative, then the set is a 1-manifold. But the only point on the level set that is a point is the point. Therefore, if it had non-zero derivative, it would be a 1-manifold.

Comment: In my diagram, there are a bunch of curves. I know that curves on a manifold are invariant under coordinate transformations. They are coordinate independeng. You will notice that, in between curves, there exists a space (ie distance) between the curves in my level set. Is that separation also invariant under coordinate transformation? That is, could I choose a set of coordinates such that the level sets could intersect? Or is that impossible...

Answer (score -1):

In general, yes, the level set is just a bunch of points. But for most functions you will see, the level set is a continuous loop. It doesn't have to be a loop or line, for instance the level set of the zero function at zero is the entire domain, which could be the entire plane. The reason that the picture you gave is the usual visualization for a level set (of a function with a 2D domain) is that it commonly arises that way from a 'well-behaved" function, for instance one that is continuous. The set of level curves is then a nice way of visualizing the gradient function or topographical maps, which only work for continuous multi-variable functions.