# Do the curves of a level set of a continuous function have to be closed?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Do the curves of a level set of a continuous function have to be closed?

**From what I understand from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1221262/197705), the curves of a level set either have to be closed or extend to infinity. If that's true, can someone explain why?**

Comment: Caution: The word "closed" in the comments and answers to your other question gets used in two (completely) different senses: _closed set_ (a set whose complement is open) and _closed curve_ (a set homeomorphic to a circle). Every level set of a continuous, real-valued function of two real variables is a _closed set_, but not generally a curve of any type at all, much less a closed curve.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea that was going on when I read it. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

You do not say how many variables are in your function. There is also an ambiguity
with the word "closed". The level set of a continuous function is a closed SET,
but by "closed curve" they usually understand a different thing.

The level set of a continuous function does not have to consists of curves, or even contain any curves, whatever you mean by a curve.

Let $E$ be any closed set. The function $f(x)=\mathrm{dist}(x,E)$ is continuous and has
$E$ as a level set. Take a straignt line segment as $E$. This is not what you call
a "closed curve", do you?