# When will level sets be closed/Jordan curves?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Are there any conditions on a $C^{1}$ function $f$, for example from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and constant $c$ which would guarantee that the level set $\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: f(x,y)=c\right\}$ is a closed curve? By "closed curve" I mean a curve which is a closed loop (homeomorphic to the circle), rather than merely a curve which, seen as a set of points, is a closed set (as discussed in comments here: [Do the curves of a level set of a continuous function have to be closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221793/do-the-curves-of-a-level-set-of-a-continuous-function-have-to-be-closed)).

Similarly, what about conditions for the level set to be a simple (non-self-intersecting) closed curve, i.e. a Jordan curve in the plane?

Comment: At least half of this follows as a specific case of the regular value theorem: if $c$ is a regular value of $f$, then the preimage $f^{-1}(c)$ is a properly embedded submanifold. In particular, it has no self-intersections.

Comment: I haven't studied manifolds yet. Would a "properly embedded submanifold" be a curve in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case?

Comment: It would be a smooth curve with no self-intersections (and some nicer properties, I think), but could fail to be bounded (i.e. could be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ rather than the circle).

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't studied manifolds yet then this answer is going to be a little rough, in that it will use some of the more sophisticated tools about smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ including Morse Theory.

Here goes.

One list of condidions that guarantees your level set is a Jordan curve is:

1. $f$ is smooth,
2. $f$ is proper,
3. $f$ has a unique critical point $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb R^2$. I'll denote
   $$b = f(x_0,y_0)
   $$
4. $c \in \text{image}(f) - \{b\}$.
5. The critical point $(x_0,y_0)$ is a Morse singularity of $f$. This just means that the matrix of second partial derivatives of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ has nonzero determinant.

Here's a few details of proof.

The Regular Value Theorem (aka the Submersion Theorem), together with 2, 3, and 4, implies that $f^{-1}(c)$ is a 1-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ for all $c \in \text{image}(f) - \{b\}$. Combining this with 1 it follows that $f^{-1}(c)$ is a compact 1-dimensional submanifold, which in turn implies that $f^{-1}(c)$ is a union of a disjoint collection of Jordan curves. Let's denote the number of components of $f^{-1}(c)$ number by $N(c)$. A further application of the Regular Value Theorem implies that $N(c)$ is locally constant: for each $c$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ so that if $c-\epsilon < c' < c+\epsilon$ then $N(c')=N(c)$.

So it remains to check that $f^{-1}(c)$ is just a single Jordan curve, in other words that $N(c)=1$ for all $c \in \text{image}(f) - \{b\}$.

The [Morse Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory), applied to $f$ and $b$, implies that $N(c)=1$ if $c$ is close to $b$.

Applying the Intermediate Value Theorem to $N(c)$ together with the fact that $N(c)$ is locally constant, it follows that $N(c)$ is constant. Knowing that $N(c)=1$ at values close to $b$, it follows that $N(c)=1$ for all values of $c$.

Comment: Would you be able to provide proof?

Comment: Didn't have time earlier, but now I've added some details of proof.

Comment: Thanks. Would this also apply to a case where $f$ has two critical points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ rather than just 1? The example I am looking at has critical points at $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ (and at both points, the matrix of second partial derivatives has non-zero determinant, as above) - would this work?

Comment: I think so, there's probably a general Morse theory argument. Properness is very important, as is controlling the cardinality of critical points. But the other conditions can probably be relaxed quite a bit.

Comment: Well, I read on Wikipedia that "Every continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is both proper and closed", and in the problem I am considering, the domain of $f$ can be restricted to the product of a closed interval for $x$ and a closed interval for $y$, which is certainly compact, so the properness condition is satisfied. I would be interested to see your or others' thoughts on a "general Morse theory argument".

Comment: Once you have a boundary, level sets can be arcs with endpoints in the boundary. So there's little hope of getting Jordan curve level sets in that situation.