# Prove that the set of points where a function of two independent variables has a constant value make a curve?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I'm quoting "Thomas' Calculus Early Transcendental 14th ed.":

> In the plane, the points where a function of two independent variables has a constant value $f (x, y) = c$ make a curve in the function’s domain. In space, the points where a function of three independent variables has a constant value $f (x, y, z) = c$ make a surface in the function’s domain.

I have a very strong intuition that the above statement is true, but I don't know how to prove it though I did make some attempts and the author seems to take that for granted.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=level+set+is+a+curve

Comment: @AnneBauval, so the statement is not entirely correct without some assumptions imposed on the function? I took that from the zhw's answer (1st one) for this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221262/are-curves-in-a-level-set-continuous

Comment: I agree with you.